# flex item width problem with display: inline-flex in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

Here is a simple illustration of the problem:

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 350px;
  background: blue;
}

.photo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fxyne157/

In Chrome and Firefox, the width of fixed-width divs inside a container div with `display: inline-flex` is not bound by the width of the parent of the container, which is what one would expect with inline-flex.

In Internet Explorer 11 however the width of the fixed-width divs is a percentage of the parent width of the flex container.

What it looks like on IE 11, even with inline-flex:

[image]

Any ideas whether or not this is a known bug, or if I am missing something obvious? How can I make the `.container` expand to as much space it needs so that all `.photo` divs are 150px regardless of the width of the `.parent` container?

Thanks!

Comment: Tried the vendor prefixes?

Comment: Yes, I tried using -ms-inline-flexbox, but I had the same result.

Comment: Ive read the inline flex box only works for the parent element and does not affect the children, ill try a pen in a min

Comment: See if this works,
http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/YWLABP

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Unfortunately that didn't work - if I wrap the .container in your pen with a .parent with width: 150px  (which I unfortunately can't remove in my use case) , then the containing children try to fit in these 150 pixels.

Comment: That did it Michael_B, thank you.

Comment: @Michael_B Still relevant in 2019. Thanks for the hint. It should be a marked answer!

Answer (score 1):

On the `.parent` element, instead of `width: 150px` use `min-width: 150px`.

On the `.photo` items, add `flex-shrink: 0`, which will disable the default setting of `flex-shrink: 1`.

IE11 is full of [flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs).

```css
.parent {
  min-width: 150px; /* adjustment */
}

.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 350px;
  background: blue;
}

.photo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 2px;
  flex-shrink: 0;  /* adjustment */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
    <div class="photo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```